# Calling a lua callback from a C library asynchronously

Tags: c, lua

I've got a C library that will call a LUA function (saved in and retrieved from the registry) periodically.  I have multiple threads that do a bunch of stuff and they all call this callback function but the call is wrapped in mutexes in order to ensure it's serialized.

My question is: would this work as expected or is there danger of the lua state being left in an inconsistent state bh the C library calling the Lua callback?
If so, what's the solution/correct approach?

Comment: Does anything in your program call into Lua other than this one callback function?

Comment: There could potentially be more than 1 callback (that's the idea) but they would all be protected with the same mutex for serialization purposes.

Comment: I should mention that everything happens through the same Lua_State I get from Lua when registering the callback. I save a pointer to it , rather than opening a new one

Comment: It is safe if ALL operations with the Lua state (invocations of any Lua C API functions) are wrapped in the mutex.

Comment: Even synchronous calls where I call a C function from Lua and the function pushes it's results on the stack and returns?  (Those are never called in another thread)

Comment: By the way, can I save the lua state argument passed from lua when calling a c function so tjat I later use it from inside C to call back into lua, perhaps from different threads (again, wrapped in mutexes to avoid race conditions)?